# CDN for SharePoint public sites

Tags: 2013, cdn

I have SharePoint 2013 Internet Published Site and it has many images, videos published for content, now our org want to go host all media files to CDN, so for SharePoint what are the best options to prepare CDN.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at SharePoint and the CDN as two separate items.  You technically have to do "nothing" to SharePoint to use a CDN, but hosting your files outside of SharePoint will change the user experience.

- For one, there will be a different place to upload whatever files you
  are targeting for the CDN, so you can't use the traditionally
  SharePoint controls or libraries.  Linking will be different.
- They'll need to know the exact path to the file in the CDN, as the
  SharePoint browse function only is for things within SharePoint.
- Cache settings will need to be determined and set on the CDN and
  you'll need to make sure those editing content are aware of them and
  what their durations are.
- You'll need to be aware of how to manage CORS policy for things like js and css
  should you chose to host them on the CDN as well as manage x-frame-options
  and Content Security Policy for anything you wish to frame or imbed
  on a SharePoint page from the CDN.